# Binding background color of listboxitem depending on certain data from the database

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I'm trying in wpf to color the background according to certain specific rules. I tried this with binding but it doesn't work.

I have 2 areas with 16 locations that I made as follows:

A.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16);

B.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16);

[2 areas with 16 locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtfaF.jpg)

In backgroundWorker_DoWork I look in the database if I have something "open" and if so I send via `A.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, UpdateMyDelegate, mystring2, mystring1);`
to the main thread 2 strings representing the area and location.

There I have (In MainWindow.cs):

```
        private void UpdateMyDelegateListbox (int mystring2, string mystring1)
        {
            

            if (mystring1 == "A")
            {
                A.SelectedItem = mystring2;
                
                VM.Background1 = something like new string () or bool somehow ??

            }
            else if (mystring1 == "B") ...
```

The idea is to check in which location is open or "Blocked" [color it red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g18Mw.png)

I just want binding. What I did now is this(xaml):

```
        <Style x:Key="SimpleListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <!--<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </Trigger>-->
                            **<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Success}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </DataTrigger>**
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

- Each area is in a stackpanel and all are in a scrollViewer
  ex:

```
<!-- Area A -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,-8" >
            <WrapPanel Width="2000" Height="500">
                <StackPanel Width="500" Height="500">
                    <ListBox x:Name="A" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="10,10,85,85" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource SimpleListBoxItem}" SelectionChanged="listboxA_SelectionChanged" >
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel ItemHeight="100"
                                   ItemWidth="100"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="local:TestApp">
                                <StackPanel Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Viewbox>
                                        <Grid x:Name="backgroundGrid"
                                      Width="48"
                                      Height="48">
                                            
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Fill="Orange" />
                                            <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                           Content="{Binding}"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                           FontSize="24"
                                           Foreground="White" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

In ViewModel I have:

```
class TestAppViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        public object _background => null;

        public string Background1
        {
            get
            {
                return Background1;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_background == value)
                {
                    return;
                }


                Background1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Background");
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Background1)));

            }
        }


    }
```

I thought of using something like IsOccupied with which to mostly transmit if at location x in area y there is something then to turn red and otherwise leave orange. I want to see in real time who are busy and who are empty.

If you can help me with any advice I would be grateful. Thank you and sorry for any mistakes of any kind, but I posted in hurry. :)

Comment: How are you supposed to change the background of an individual item if you have only one `Background1` property? Or where is `Background1` defined? How are you using `TestAppViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `ItemsSource` to a collection of objects that have a property that decides the background:

```
A.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => new TestAppViewModel(x));
```

Add an `int` property to the `TestAppViewModel` class:

```
class TestAppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public TestAppViewModel(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public int Number { get; }

    public object _background;
    public string Background1
    {
        get
        {
            return Background1;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_background == value)
                return;

            _background = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Background1");
        }
    }
}
```

And bind to the source properties in your template:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="local:TestApp">
        <StackPanel Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid x:Name="backgroundGrid"
                        Width="48"
                        Height="48">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Fill="{Binding Background1}" />
                    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                           Content="{Binding Number}"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                           FontSize="24"
                                           Foreground="White" />
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have generated a constructor in my ViewModel to be able to use private `PickByLightViewModel VM = new PickByLightViewModel();` and then with the number the binding was done successfully but not with the fill.

Here I have TestApp:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TestAppViewModel VM = new TestAppViewModel ();
        private static BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            A.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => new TestAppViewModel (x));
            B.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => new TestAppViewModel (x));
            C.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => new TestAppViewModel (x));
            D.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => new TestAppViewModel (x));
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;


            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker

            {

                WorkerReportsProgress = true,

                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true

            };
 

            backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;

            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
  private delegate void UpdateMyDelegatedelegate(int mystring2, string mystring1);
        private void UpdateMyDelegateListbox(int mystring2, string mystring1)
        {
            if (mystring1 == "A")
            {
                A.SelectedIndex = mystring2;
                VM.Background1 = "Red";
             
            }
            else if (mystring1 == "B")...
```

Yes, you are right, thank you very much for the explanations.
I made some changes but it still doesn't work if I used for example:  `VM.Background1 = "Red";` if I do binding like that then I receive a StackOverflow Exception.